# Rollback en Django

Tags: python, django, transacciones

Quizá en Django existe la forma de hacer un rollback en caso de fallo de transacciones como insert, update, delete, es decir, normalmente el código para insertar sería algo así:

```
nuevo_elemento = MiModelo(
    elemento1 = valor1,
    elemento2 = valor2,
    ...
    ...
    etc
)
nuevo_elemento.save()
```

Bien, con esto basicamente creo o guardo un elemento en Django, pero qué pasa si esto va en un bucle:

```
for item in list_productos:
   nuevo_producto = Producto(
       elemento1 = item
       ...
   )
   nuevo_producto.save()
```

Y al ejecutar esto inserta varios de ellos pero por cualquier percance o error no insertó todos los elementos de la `list_productos`, ¿cómo hago ese rollback evitando así insertar unos pocos y no todos los requeridos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto, Django trabaja en modo **autocommit**, esto quiere decir que cada vez que haces un query este es enviado inmediatamente a la base de datos. Lo que tú necesitas hacer es [controlar las transacciones explícitamente](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) para asegurar la atomicidad de una función o un bloque de código, es decir, que todo los queries que se ejecuten dentro de un bloque de código sea todo (si salió todo bien) o nada (si ocurrió un error en el proceso se hace rollback).

Para esto tienes dos opciones.

1. Declarar una función como atómica usando un decorador:

   ```
   from django.db import transaction

   @transaction.atomic
   def viewfunc(request):
       # Todo lo que está en esta función se ejecuta dentro de una transacción
       # ...
   ```
2. Por bloque de código usando un context manager:

   ```
   from django.db import transaction

   def viewfunc(request):
       # Esta parte del código se ejecuta en modo autocommit (por defecto).
       # ...

       with transaction.atomic():
           # Esto se ejecuta dentro de una transacción.
           # ...
   ```